# Cannot Set Focus on ComboBox with DropDownStyle DropDown

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a Combobox. I changed the DropDownStyle from DropDownList to DropDown. After I did this, the Combobox no longer has focus when the form is invoked. Does anyone have a solution to set the focus again?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming WinForms, what is the TabIndex of this Control? Anyway, you can can set the ActiveControl to this Control in Form.Load (if it's enabled).

Comment: `DropDown` is the default. Are you sure that you don't mean that you changed it from `DropDown` to `DropDownList`? I just created a new project with a `ComboBox` and `Button` and, when I changed the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` it did not display a focus rectangle when the form was first displayed but, when I put `Console.WriteLine(ActiveControl.Name)` in the `Shown` event handler, it told me that it was `ComboBox1`. I suspect that there is no actual issue and you simply haven't tested properly.

Comment: I also added some items and used the down arrow key as soon as the form was displayed and the selection did change as expected. I then changed the `DropDownStyle` back to `DropDown` and it still worked as expected. If all you did really was change the `DropDownStyle` and that affected the focus behaviour beyond the drawing of a focus rectangle then your system is broken. If your system is not broken, you must have done something else besides.